# JavaScript is not setting the resultant value into <p>'s innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
    Calculator
    </title>
    <script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
  <h1> Calculator </h1>
  <form>
    <input id="txt1" type="text" />
       &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 

    <input id="rad1" type="radio" value="add" />add &nbsp
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" value="mul" />mul &nbsp
    <input id="rad3" type="radio" value="div" />div &nbsp
    <input id="rad4" type="radio" value="sub" />sub &nbsp

      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <input id="txt2" type="text" />
    <button id="mButton" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate!!</button>
  </form>
<p id="resultP">Result will be displayed here:</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is JavaScript:

```
function calculate()
{
  var first = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var sec = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  var result;
  if (document.getElementById('rad1').checked) {
    result = parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('rad2').checked) {
    result = first * sec;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('rad3').checked) {
    result = first / sec;
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('rad4').checked) {
    result = first - sec;
  }
  alert(result);
  var resultP = document.getElementById('resultP');
  resultP.innerHTML = result;
};
```

Upto `alert(result);` works fine. But it is not setting the result in that p tag. Also, when I press Calculate, whole page blinks, and the values entered in both input fields are gone.

And also when I press Calculate, the link on the address bar is changed to `/htmlCode.html?arithematic2=mul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page blinks because it reloads. The default `<button>` type in forms is `submit`. Your JavaScript code doesn't block submitting the form, thus after executing the `calculate` it redirects to the same page adding all form data to the URL.

You should either define the button as

```
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

or attach the `calculate` function as form's `submit` event handler and block the submission, e.g. using pure HTML attributes:

```
<form onsubmit="calculate(); return false;">
```

Comment: yes okay, it did the trick. But this raises another question. I have never done this before and things were working fine. Why should I have to `return false` now ?

Comment: `onsubmit`, `onclick`, `onsomething` attributes define code that is executed when an event is triggered on an element (form, link, button, etc.). Some events have a **defined default browser action**, e.g. after form submit event, the browser sends that form to a URL. When code inside the `onsomething` attribute returns `false` it blocks the default browser action, because you "told" the browser that you handled the event with your code.

Comment: I am sure you are right. But all I am saying is, I used to do [exactly this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml) and things used to work out perfectly fine. Is it changed now? It it some kind of new standard for browsers?

Comment: No, nothing has changed since many many years. In the example from your link, you don't have to block default action, because clicking on `<p>` doesn't have a default browser action (or the "worst" default action is text selection). In your case, you have a `<button>` **inside a form**. And a button without `type` attribute is **submit** button by default. Clicking on it submits the form. That's specified in HTML standard. Your JavaScript executed without problems, but after that your page got reloaded, because the form was sent to current document. And this default action you want to block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### HTML

```
<h1> Calculator </h1>
  <form>
    <input id="txt1" type="text" />    
    <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="a" value="add" />add 
    <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="a" value="mul" />mul
    <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="a" value="div" />div
    <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="a" value="sub" />sub
    <input id="txt2" type="text" />
    <button id="mButton" value="Calculate" onclick="return calculate()">Calculate!!</button>
  </form>
<p>Result will be displayed here: <span id="resultP"></span></p>
```

### JavaScript

```
    function calculate()
    {       
        var first = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var sec = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
        var result;
        if (document.getElementById('rad1').checked) {
                    result = parseInt(first) + parseInt(sec);
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('rad2').checked) {
                    result = first * sec;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('rad3').checked) {
            result = first / sec;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('rad4').checked) {
            result = first - sec;
        }
                
        var resultP = document.getElementById('resultP');
        resultP.innerHTML = result;
    
        return false;//this will prevent the default action
   }
```

Comment: i like the idea of `<span>` :)

Comment: @BugsHappen: also use unique name for radio button group, The name setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. I thought that was achieved by making another form and radio buttons in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because pressing the event fires form that would prevent this from happening you need to silence the event when clicked.
`function calculate(event) { event.preventDefault() ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button, and it will work fine

```
type='button'
```